# OS 11 NSSortDescriptor for fetchRequest not working

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest, ios11, nssortdescriptor

After update to iOS 11 the sorting of Core Data objects using NSSortDescriptor stopped working. With iOS 10 still works fine.

I'm making a sorted array. Key "objectId" has type NSNumber. (This is not an objectID of managed object).

```
let sortedCalls = UBCall.fetchInContext(context!) { request in
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "game == %@ && isSuggested != YES && isPreferred != YES", self)
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "objectId", ascending: true)]
}
```

Currently, on devices and simulators with iOS 11 the sortedCall is not a sorted array.

Please, help. Any ideas? My app is in AppStore and after update to new version of the iOS, it becomes totally unusable.

Thanks.

Comment: `fetchInContext()` looks like a custom method, the issue is likely in there as this is not the normal pattern for a fetch request.

Comment: This methods works fine with iOS 10. And I've tried to init context directly. It won't help. The methods has next implementation: 

public static func fetchInContext(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext, configurationBlock: (NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) -> () = { _ in }) -> [Self] {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: Self.entityName)
        configurationBlock(request)
        guard let result = try! context.fetch(request) as? [Self] else { fatalError("Fetched objects have wrong type") }
        return result
    }

Comment: First, the code you put in your comment should be added to your question. If you put at least four spaces before each line of code it will get put into a code block like the code I edited for you. That will make it way more readable. Second, does the predicate have any effect on the results? You might be better off making a method that is `fetchIn(context: , withPredicate: , andSortDescriptors: )` that eliminates the need to mutate an object inside a closure.

Comment: Thanks for your notes, but that didn't help me either. The array is not sorted anyway.

Comment: Does the predicate have any effect on the results? Or are you getting all of the the `UBCall`s back no matter what?

Comment: I'm getting all UBCalls which are related to the current object Game.

Comment: Make sure the objectId is different in each one, maybe the issue is that isn't getting set correctly rather than a sorting issue. Use a breakpoint or a for loop with a print statement that prints all the objectId values.